# Accessing all uncaught exceptions from terminate handler

Tags: c++, exception, terminate-handler

I'm currently following C++ core guidelines setting all destructors in my code to be `noexcept`. Some of my destructors may potentially throw exceptions - in that case I would like the program to crash and provide me with details on what caused the crash. Setting the `noexcept` specifier on the destructor will call `std::terminate()` which in turns invoke the default `terminate_handler`. The default `terminate_handler` will print the exception which was fired inside the destructor. This is great in the case in which the throwing destructor was not called while another exception was being thrown. In that case I would like the `terminate_handler` to print both exceptions so I can know what triggered the error handling path in the first place.

The problem is I can't seem to find a way in the standard library to get the uncaught exception. There's a `std::current_exception()` function which gets the exception being handled and `std::uncaught_exceptions()` which only gets the number of uncaught exception. I would like to get an `std::exception_ptr` or something to the uncaught exceptions. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

See: https://www.danielseither.de/blog/2013/12/globally-handling-uncaught-exceptions-and-signals-in-c/

```
std::exception_ptr exptr = std::current_exception();
try {
    std::rethrow_exception(exptr);
}
catch (std::exception &ex) {
    std::fprintf(stderr, "Terminated due to exception: %s\n", ex.what());
}
```

Comment: OP said `std::current_exception` is not enough for him since it will only provide one exception.

Comment: You just run this until the total number of pending exceptions has been caught.

Comment: In general BTW, you should not let std::terminate execute. If you label a function as noexcept, you should be wrapping all of the code in that function in a catch all and handling the exception there, so although the code above will work fine, in general, letting exceptions stack like that and relying on std::terminate is a bad idea.